# Replacing a column in a dataframe with another dataframe column using partial string match

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, merge

I have the large CSVs with following sample dataframes:

```
df1 = 
Index    Fruit   Vegetable    
    0    Mango   Spinach
    1    Berry   Carrot
    2    Banana  Cabbage
```

```
df2 = 
Index   Unit                   Price
   0    Mango_123              30
   1    234_Artichoke_CE       45
   2    23_Banana              12
   3    Berry___LE             10
   4    Cabbage___12LW         25
   5    Rice_ww_12             40
   6    Spinach_KJ             34
   7    234_Carrot_23          08
   8    10000_Lentil           12
   9    Pot________12          32
```

I would like to replace the names in df2 to replace the names in df1 to create the following dataframe:

```
df3= 
Index    Fruit        Vegetable    
    0    Mango_123    Spinach_KJ
    1    Berry___LE   234_Carrot_23
    2    23_Banana    Cabbage___12LW
```

What would be a generic way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Update: Fuzzy matching does not work well for my dataset. I would appreciate a way using regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fuzzy matching with [`thefuzz.process.extractOne`](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz), that will compute the closest match using [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
# pip install thefuzz

from thefuzz import process

cols = ['Fruit', 'Vegetable']
df1[cols] = df1[cols].applymap(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df2['Unit'])[0])
```

output:

```
   Index       Fruit       Vegetable
0      0   Mango_123      Spinach_KJ
1      1  Berry___LE   234_Carrot_23
2      2   23_Banana  Cabbage___12LW
```

Comment: It does not work well for my dataset, I would prefer an implementation based on string match if possible.

Comment: Please give details on how it does not work and give a concrete example of the data

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the dataset. I am accepting the answer since it works for the example I gave. In my dataset, df1 also contains underscore and number before and after the name. Therefore, the fuzzy logic assigns wrong unit names under the Fruit and Vegetable columns based on the distance it calculates.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be better solved by using list comprehension:

```
fruit_list = [df2.Unit[df2.Unit.str.contains(x)].values[0] for x in df1.Fruit.tolist()]
vegetable_list = [df2.Unit[df2.Unit.str.contains(x)].values[0] for x in df1.Vegetable.tolist()]
```

Above code will create two lists, one will extract all the fruits from df2 while other will do the same for vegetables. Then, create a new df and do the following:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Fruit", "Vegetable"])
df3["Fruit"] = fruit_list
df3["Vegetable"] = vegetable_list
```